# Восстановить ошибку в firewall и убрать неправильное правило

Tags: linux, firewall, opensuse

Пытался наугад добавить правила

```
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 52.0.0.0/8 -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j DROP
firewall-cmd --direct --permanent --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 52.0.0.0/8 --dport 3478 -j DROP
```

firewall-cmd выдал `success` и дальнейшие действия выдают ошибку.

Как убрать ошибку в firewall и неправильное правило?

```
# firewall-cmd --reload
Error: COMMAND_FAILED: Direct: '/usr/sbin/iptables-restore -w -n'  
failed: iptables-restore v1.8.7 (legacy): unknown option "--dport"  
Error occurred at line: 5  
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

*Отключил **FirewallD**, так как при попытке его включения - отключается **SSH** доступ. Надо как-то надёжнее исправить ситуацию без личного присутствия у сервера.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во втором правиле не указан модуль который будет обрабатывать --dport

Нужно например `-m tcp` или `-p tcp` добавить.

Убрать строчку можно так:

Сначала `systemctl stop firewalld.service`

Потом в `/etc/firewalld/direct.xml` удаляешь строку `<rule ...`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<direct>  
  <rule ipv="ipv4" table="filter" chain="FORWARD" priority="0">-s 192.168.0.0/16 -d 52.0.0.0/8 --dport 3478 -j DROP</rule>
</direct>
```

Comment: удалил лишнюю строку.  ошибка исчезла. но SSH/HTTP/HTTPS доступ не даётся. буду искать

Comment: все простые разрешения SSH/HTTP/HTTPS исчезли. Перезагрузиться или всё писать по-новой?

Comment: @AlexGlebe кроме директ там есть ещё политики и зоны есть. `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`

Comment: жалко, что добавил кучу всего в зону public. И из-за ошибки всё испарилось.

Comment: если не добавлял --permanent, то пиши поновой